# Separate build for each device

Tags: blackberry, java-me

There are plenty of Blackberry devices available. Some devices are touch enabled phones.

Since the BlackBerry phone models are different from each other, do I need to have a separate build for each device?

If not, what is the procedure for developing a BlackBerry app for different BlackBerry devices?

Comment: For 5.0 OS and above,you can use same build for touch as well as non touch devices,but if you are 4.6 OS,we need  to take different build.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use updated feature of the updated OS,then its fine.You can create single code for each device.

But if you want to use the latest feature like touch event etc.then you have to implement code for both-touch and non-touch ,create .cod file for each and define path for each in application.alx file.

As given below.

```
<application id="bgapp1">

    <name >

    </name>
    <description >

    </description>
    <version >
        1.0.0
    </version>
    <vendor >
        BlackBerry Developer
    </vendor>
    <copyright >
        Copyright (c) 2011 BlackBerry Developer
    </copyright>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[4.5.0,4.5.1)">
        <directory >
            4.5.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[4.6.0,4.6.1)">
        <directory >
            4.6.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[4.6.1,4.6.2)">
        <directory >
            4.6.1
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[4.7.0,4.7.1)">
        <directory >
            4.7.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[5.0.0)">
        <directory >
            5.0.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
            <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[6.0.0)">
        <directory >
            6.0.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            bgapp1.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that you have to consider due to the differences between BlackBerry devices. Here are a few factors to consider;

-Operating System (e.g. 4.6, 5.0, 6.0): There may be features in newer OSs that you might want to take advantage of that are not available on an older OS. You can wrap code in pre-processor directives or have separate files wherever your code base deviates in this respect. BB OS 4.7 introduced touch screen capabilities.

-Screen Resolution: You might need to modify your layout, images you use such as background graphics or other UI elements based on the available screen real estate. Some popular resolutions are 320x240, 480x360, devices yet to release are expected to be 800x480.

The typical development procedure involves you setting up a separate build for each device configuration (resolution and os combination, as several devices share the same configuration). You can use Ant and BB-Ant-Tools for that.

If you're just starting BB development, I recommend that you invest your efforts in BB 5.0+, if not 6.0 as a minimum. For most people, this is good advice (tried and true on my part).